# Scrollarea with fixed dimensions

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlabel, qscrollarea

I'm sorry for the title but I cannont explain the topic in a better way.

I've a scrollarea with gridlayout which has a variable number of rows and cols. In every cell of the grid I've a QLabel.
I would like that the viewport of the scrollarea has a fixed size, so I can view only a certain number of label without using the scrollbar.
In this code, instead, I view all the labels and if their number variates they are always inserted in the space of viewport with their dimensions changed.

I should do this without changing the line self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(False), because the zoom system that I'm implementing does not work if it is set to True.

Is it possible?

```
import sys


from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import ( QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout, QApplication, QMainWindow,
                             QLabel, QWidget, QPushButton, QScrollArea
                             )



class MyScrollingArea(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyScrollingArea).__init__()
        self.vertLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vertLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.vertLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.gridContainer = QWidget()
        self.scrollArea = QScrollArea()
        self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(False)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.gridContainer)
        self.populate( )
        buttonsArea=self.zoomMenu()
        self.gridContainer.setLayout(self.gridLayout )
        self.vertLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.vertLayout.addWidget(buttonsArea)
        self.setLayout(self.vertLayout )

    def zoomMenu(self):
           widButtonFooter = QWidget()
           layButtonFooter = QHBoxLayout()
           widButtonFooter.setLayout(layButtonFooter)
           butZommMinus = QPushButton("-")
           butZommPlus = QPushButton("+")
           layButtonFooter.addWidget(butZommMinus)
           layButtonFooter.addWidget(butZommPlus) 
           return widButtonFooter

    def populate(self):
        colors = (  "navy","green", "magenta","cyan", "yellow","red", "orange", "blue","purple", "gold","silver", "lightblue", "lime" )
        for row in range(0,10):
            for col in range (0,20):
                self.addLabel(row,col,colors[row])

    def addLabel(self,row,col,color):
        label = MyLabel(row,col,80,100,color,str(row) + "." + str(col))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(label,row,col) 

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.gridContainer.resize(self.width(), self.height())
        super(MyScrollingArea, self).resizeEvent(event)



class MyLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self,row,col, w, h, color, text):
        super().__init__()
        self.color=color
        self.setStyleSheet("border:10px solid " + self.color + ";")
        self.setText(text)
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, w, h))

    def mousePressEvent(self,QMouseEvent):
        if QMouseEvent.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.setStyleSheet("background-color:" + self.color + ";")
        elif QMouseEvent.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            self.setStyleSheet("border:10px solid " + self.color + ";")

class MyGrid(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(1000, 800)
        self.saScrollMeasureBox = MyScrollingArea()
        widPanelMeasure = QWidget()
        layvPanelMeasure = QVBoxLayout()
        widPanelMeasure.setLayout(layvPanelMeasure)
        layvPanelMeasure.addWidget(self.saScrollMeasureBox)
        self.setCentralWidget(widPanelMeasure)
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyGrid()

    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: screenshoots application]

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding what you want. Are those "labels" going to have always the same size, possibly based on the zoom level? Could you provide some images showing the expected result(s)? Also, consider that setting the geometry of a widget that is going to be added to a layout is completely useless, as the layout will override that geometry anyway.

Comment: Thank you! I just want to understand the interaction of different widgets when we have to specify their size. Can I post an image in the comment? Or do I have to modify the main message?

Comment: That is a very broad subject, which can become really complex when dealing with scroll areas. The base concept is that layout managers do exactly what their name says: they *manage* the layout of items, their sizes and their position, taking into consideration possible constraints (minimum/maximum sizes), size *hints* (the preferred size) and *policies* (how a widget can be resized by the layout). That's why setting the geometry is pointless: the layout is responsible of that. If you want fixed sizes, then use `setFixedSize()`.

Comment: Then, you're saying that "the zoom system that I'm implementing does not work if it is set to True". What "zoom system"? I suggest you to clarify what you're doing and what you need to achieve, if that "zoom system" is mandatory, you should explain us what it does, how and why (possibly by expanding your code). If you want to provide an image, add it to the post; your current reputation won't allow you to embed them, but other users will be able to edit it in order to display it.

Comment: I'm just studying the GUI so it is more important for me now how something works.
If I set to true this value, I've the layout I want (left side of the image) but it is not resizable. 
So my first question is: is there a way to obtain the layout in the left side by using some attribute of the content widget and not with a flag of the layout?
Because I don't understand this layout behaviour and this is important for me if I want to understand these libraries and not only make the application work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A layout manager doesn't have a specific size, but only a size hint and possibly a minimum and/or maximum size, all based on the items it contains, using their size hints, constraints and policies.

Setting a geometry on a widget that is going to be added to a layout is pointless, as the layout *manages* their sizes and positions. The solution is to use `setFixedSize` instead.

Since a layout also automatically adjusts the positions of widgets if there's space left (and none of them is able to expand its size), you can add a stretch at the end of the layout in order to ensure that they are always spaced in the same way even if there's more space available on the edges. For boxed layouts, it's enough to use `addStretch()`, but for grid layouts you have to specify the stretch for specific rows and columns instead.

To better understand how Qt deals with all these (broad and complex) aspects, I suggest you to read more about [hints and policies](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#size-hints-and-size-policies), [QSizePolicy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html) and [layout management](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), and do some more experiments with more *simple* cases, even using [Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html).

The following modifications require that the `widgetResizable` property is set to `True`.

```
class MyScrollingArea(QWidget):
    # ...
    def populate(self):
        colors = (
            "navy", "green", "magenta", "cyan", "yellow", "red", "orange", 
            "blue", "purple", "gold", "silver", "lightblue", "lime"
        )
        rows = 10
        columns = 20
        for row in range(rows):
            for col in range (columns):
                self.addLabel(row, col, colors[row])
        self.gridLayout.setColumnStretch(columns, 1)
        self.gridLayout.setRowStretch(rows, 1)


class MyLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, row, col, w, h, color, text):
        super().__init__()
        self.color = color
        self.setStyleSheet("border:10px solid " + self.color + ";")
        self.setText(text)
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setFixedSize(w, h)
```

<sup>I suggest you to be more careful with spaces, which should always be used when following a comma (and around the equal sign) in order to improve readability. Read more on the official [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).</sup>

Comment: Thank you, I will study all the links in your answer.

Thanks for style suggestions too :)

Comment: @Nunkij you're very welcome. Remember that if an answer solves your issue, you should mark it as accepted by clicking on the gray tickmark on its left (it is one of the many ways to gain reputation, which will also give you more privileges, such as the ability to post images; see [What is reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)).

Comment: As you can see I'm new of this site, I didn't know this feature. I will test the code as soon I can so I can click the button :)
Thank you again!